# Language Design/Conlang in Sound Art: Do you know any examples?

Tags: speech, sound-art, creature-vocalizations

Hi,
I'm going to do a project of language design, that is the creation of an artificial language like it happens, for example, for the aliens of some sc-fi movies.
(Famous examples are the aliens in District 9 and Chewbecca in Star Wars (of course ;)).
It is also called "conlang" (constructed language).
This is a project for the Sound Design course of of my Art School and the final work should be some kind of a "speaking installation", where the speech is an artificial language.

My plans are to collect a database of sounds/phonems from human speeches of different languages, in addiction to synthetic sounds,and find a way to re-arrange them on the fly when triggered by an interaction with the audience, in order to create "sentences".

The techniques used to create aliens/creatures languages for movies and videogames have been widely discussed, also here on SSD.
**What I'd like to know instead, if there are examples of artificial language design in Sound Art or Arts in general.**

No videogames or films involved this time ;)

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated!!
Thanks!
Max

Comment: Cool stuff, was just thinking about this topic last night. Very ambitious project, please post updates as you go along!

Answer (score 1):

Tolkien's Middle Earth languages comes to mind, although of course they have been used in the Lord of the Rings films. Also Anthony Burges' A Clockwork Orange uses Nadsat, a conlag based on Russian.

Answer (score 1):

Two people come to mind when I think of language and sound art.

Diana Deutsch and Kurt Schwitters

Kurt Schwitters has a famous sound work called "Ursonate". It is phonetically based and may give you some ideas of structure or the way a language can sound.
Links to listen to "Ursonate" on this page:  http://www.ubu.com/sound/schwitters.html

Diana Deutsch is a psychologist rather than artist but has some great research on sound and speech and perception. You can find a lot online about her work.

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: excellent reference with ursonate...how did i forget the whole dada movement?!

Answer (score 0):

What a great project, I'd also be really interested in hearing your results. Sounds like perfect Max/MSP territory. Program in some universal rules taken from aspects of languages around the world as a basis for your sound triggers possibly? Play around with convolution, you could take the articulation of one language and convolve it to another? Soundhack could be a great tool for this or logic's space designer. 
Best of luck...
Phil